# How do I track search queries with Google Analytics when my search engine uses a hash for the query?

Tags: google-analytics, url, tracking, search

My company's search engine generates a hash/pound sign (#) instead of a question mark for search queries: `Search.htm#search-` followed by exactly the user's input string.

```
http://www.example.com/productVersion/content/Search.htm#search-users search terms here
```

As you can see, it's clearly not a key-value query pair.

For the **Query parameter** setting in GA, I've tried various forms of `#search-`, `search-`, and just `search`, but GA really seems to key off the URL query parameter (a question mark).

What can I do? I'm using `analytics.js`, not `ga.js`, so please don't try pushing [`_setAllowAnchor()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowAnchor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA by default excludes anything after a fragment, but if you wanted to include that into your page reports, or other reports, you would need to overwrite the `page` parameter, like this;

```
var newPath = document.location.pathname + document.location.search + document.location.hash;
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page':newPath});
```

Comment: That more or less did the trick. I modified it a bit to rewrite the hash into a query and send that back instead. Thanks for the help!